# Bootstrap table row content vertically centered

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, center

I'm trying to center the content of my bootstrap table so they line up with the image.

`Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t4GHt/`

I have no idea what to do, I tried many things but nothing seems to work.
Hopefully someone here has a (simple) trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want your text aligned to the vertical center of your images, all you have to do is apply the following CSS rule:

```
.table>tbody>tr>td {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```